# How to restrict user from entering direct url

Tags: php

I have some files that can be accessed by admin and permitted by admin that user. But the problem is that, a third user can enter the URL directly and he can also access that page, so how do I restrict the unauthorized user from accessing it?
eg: www.manoj.com/myinfo.php /// can be accessed by admin
eg: www.manoj.com/myinfo.php /// can be accessed by user who is allowed by admin

But a third user is also able to access this page by entering the url directly. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You need to add some auth logic.

Comment: We can not restrict user to put URL in browser, you need to check user before render the respective page.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+restrict+user+access Maybe you should try searching first to see if you can find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1)i think third user is stranger who may try to attempt the url.
Hope you are Using [**Session**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for managing multi-users,you must be checking the sessions on the top of the page to check valid login credentials(user is logged in or not). 
 so any 3rd user attempt to url will be redirected to the login.

Comment: url accessing user id or role and check  that accessed user session is matched with required role or not